# SSIS execution timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, ssis-2016

Recently I started to get this error from time to time on my nightly SSIS jobs:
Message

> Executed as user: "my user name". Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  00:01:01  Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904. Server: "my server name", Package path: "my package path.dtsx", Environment reference Id: NULL.  Description: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider  Started:  00:01:01  Finished: 00:01:31  Elapsed:  30.61 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Usually my job finishes successfully but this keeps happening from time to time.

I am using SQL Server agent.

On my package all timeouts are set to 0 (no timeout). Server remote timeout is set to 600.

No jobs are running at the time I want to start this one except SSIS Server Maintenance Job (same situation on failures and successful job finishes).

There are some similar questions but most of them are not answered and the rest failed to help me.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: is it a VM or a physical machine?

Comment: When package is updated in Integration Services Catalogs, you need to check it in the job, to see if everything fine, eg. environment reference is set correctly.

Comment: @StijnWynants , it is a physical machine

Comment: @Wendy , how is that related to this issue? Since everything usually works fine. Even after the job failed I restared the job manually and it successfully completed without any problems. Package was not being updated at any time.

Comment: Is there something in the sql server error log?

Comment: What is the job doing? How many steps within the package? Does it have any logging? (If not add some.)

Comment: @StijnWynants , there's a warning that I found in Event Viewer logs that has a date that's pretty close: "Database Access Error. Cause [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 88) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.. (FWB 00090)". I don't know if it's related, however these jobs are scheduled to start every-night at midnight (when there are no other processes running except for these jobs).  No errors found.

Comment: @Peter , broadly speaking the job sends emails. It does have a logging. However, job history says that it fails at the step 1. My further inspection showed that it doesn't even start properly - it seems like the problem is related to starting of the job, not the job content (which explains why the job in most cases works perfectly fine, even when rerunning again the same day).

Comment: @StijnWynants , disregard my latest comment about warning - it is certainly not related to the issue.

Comment: Re: "These jobs are scheduled to start at midnight". How many jobs? If there is a lot happening at the time it may be worth staggering the schedule, or insert a delay step in the agent job.

Comment: Is this all running on a single server? Agent job, SSIS and SQL target db? And is the package deployed to SSIS catalog or on the file system?

Comment: @Peter , there are about 10 jobs, however they are scheduled to run synchronously. All of this is running on a single server. The package is deployed to SSIS catalog.

Comment: @Peter my latest guess is that SSIS Server Maintenance Job (which is the only one running at the same time as I have mentioned in question) sometimes somehow affects my problematic job. If I dont find a clrear solution to this problem, I will reschedule the job and make it to retry in case of a failure.

Comment: Is there an error on the server running the SSIS at the specific time?

Comment: @StijnWynants , no, there are no errors on the server running the SSIS.

Comment: Do you have monitoring on storage & Network? do you see high latencies or hickups for that specific timeframe?

Comment: @StijnWynants no, I do not monitor storage and network. I do have enough of storage though.

Comment: I just happened to be looking SSISDB and found this post from MS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2972285/fix-performance-issues-when-you-use-ssisdb-as-your-deployment-store-in